# Powershell When Running ForEach loop loosing values in array

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

After running the below foreach command i am left with the last value in the array and the others go missing. Can someone help please?

```
$InternationalSupportedList = @("GBR","USA","SAU","HKG","AUS", "AUT")

    foreach ($InternationalSupportedList in $InternationalSupportedList) {

    run-MySQLQuery -ConnectionString "$DatabaseSrvIP;$MysqlUid;$MysqlPwd;$MysqlDatabase;" -Query "
    SELECT 'Title', 'Location', 'Company', 'URL', 'Description', 'Salary', 'Type', 'Source', 'SourceType', 'Date', 'Rank_Score', 'Title_Keyword'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Title,Location,Company,URL,Description,Salary,Type,Source,SourceType,Date,Rank_Score,Title_Keyword
    FROM ${ProjectName}
    Where Country = '${InternationalSupportedList}'
    INTO OUTFILE 'U:/test/Csv-Output/${ProjectName}/${ProjectName}_${InternationalSupportedList}.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '`"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';";

    }
```

So if i go to view $InternationalSupportedList in Powershell ISE i get AUT and the rest are missing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the same variable twice in the `foreach` clause. This leaves it referring to the last item in the collection after the enumeration completes.

Try

```
foreach ($InternationalSupportedItem in $InternationalSupportedList)
```

And modify the query string to reference `$InternationalSupportedItem` instead of `$InternationalSupportedList`

Does the script otherwise work? I'm not sure the referencing variables using the form `"${variablename}"` will work. The usual form is simply `"$variablename"` or by subexpression `"$($variablename)"`.